# Open sets in topology

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a set and $\tau$ a collection of subsets of $X$ such that $X$ and $\emptyset$ are in $\tau$, arbitrary union and finite intersection of elements of $\tau$ belong to $\tau$. Is there any other family, say $\mu$, of subsets of $X$ with the same properties?

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking here. By definition, the elements of a topology are called "open". You don't really *find* that "a collection which is a topology contains open sets", you *define* it that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Wikipedia article [Open set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_set) states:

> The topological definition of open sets generalizes the metric space definition: If one begins with a metric space and defines open sets as before, then the family of all open sets is a topology on the metric space. Every metric space is therefore, in a natural way, a topological space. There are, however, topological spaces that are not metric spaces.

Give a base set, there are many topological spaces on
that base set. Some of them come from several metrics 
defined on the base set. Thus, there is a clear link
between a metric on a base set and its associated
topology, but other than that, there are many different
idependent topologies and metrics on the same base set.

Comment: Thank you, Sir.

Comment: Then can we say, open sets in a topological space need not be open in a metric space defined on same set$X$

Answer (score 0):

Metric spaces induce a natural topology. The set of all open sets of a metric space M is a topology on M. However, every non-hausdorff topological space is non metrizable.

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you are asking this:

> Let $X$ be a set and $\tau$ a collection of subsets of $X$ such that $X$ and $\emptyset$ are in $\tau$, arbitrary union and finite intersection of elements of $\tau$ belong to $\tau$. Is there any other family, say $\mu$, of subsets of $X$ with the same properties?

If this is what you meant to ask, then the answer is affirmative.
We can explain it by examples:

1. The discrete topology (every subset of $X$ is open) and indiscrete topology (the only open sets are $X$ and $\emptyset$) where $X$ has at least two elements.
2. Standard topology and [Sorgenfrey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) topology in $\mathbb{R}$.
3. Any two nonequvalent metric spaces.